# Postman and Jira API

Tags: javascript, postman, jira, postman-collection-runner

How can I modify this code to classify the category labels of the items: f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5? Currently, the code is only classifying items with [f1, f2] labels, but it doesn't display other labels if they are alone or different from f1 and f2.

code:

```
pm.test("Status da resposta é 200 OK", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var items = jsonData.issues;
const maxResults = parseInt(jsonData.maxResults);
const startAt = parseInt(jsonData.startAt);
const total = parseInt(jsonData.total);

console.log("O total de itens é " + total);
console.log("A paginação está em " + startAt);

if (startAt <= total) {
  console.log("Iniciando teste...");

  var labelCounts = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var labels = item.fields.labels;

    for (var j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {
      var label = labels[j];
      if (labelCounts.hasOwnProperty(label.toLowerCase())) {
        labelCounts[label.toLowerCase()]++;
      } else {
        labelCounts[label.toLowerCase()] = 1;
      }
    }

    console.log("Item com as labels:", item.key, labels);
  }

  for (var label in labelCounts) {
    if (labelCounts.hasOwnProperty(label)) {
      console.log("Número de itens com a label " + label + ":", labelCounts[label]);
    }
  }

  pm.collectionVariables.set("startAt", startAt + maxResults);

  console.log("Próxima página: " + (startAt + maxResults));

  pm.sendRequest({
    // envia nova requisição para a próxima página
    url: pm.variables.get("url"),
    method: 'GET',
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + pm.variables.get("token")
    },
    params: {
      jql: encodeURIComponent(pm.variables.get("jql")),
      fields: "labels",
      startAt: pm.variables.get("startAt"),
      maxResults: pm.variables.get("maxResults")
    }
  }, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Status da resposta da próxima página: " + res.code);
    }
  });
}
```

URL: {{url}}?jql=project%20%3D%2012946%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Done%20AND%20updated%20%3E%3D%20startOfMonth(%22-1%22)%20AND%20updated%20%3C%3D%20endOfMonth(%22-1%22)%20AND%20labels%20%3D%20f2&fields=labels

console response:
Item com as labels:
PID-5177
(2) ["F1", "f2"]

Item com as labels:
PID-5118
(2) ["F1", "f2"]

Item com as labels:
PID-4998
(2) ["F1", "f2"]

Item com as labels:
PID-4920
(2) ["F1", "f2"]

Número de itens com a label f1:
4

Número de itens com a label f2:
4

I apologize for the confusion. Here's the modified code to display items with any of the category labels f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5